# String Manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, string

I've got a string in php it can be in one of two formats - either:

```
"example1" AND somethingelse = "example2"
```

or just

```
"example1"
```

All I need is to get the data in the speechmarks, whether both or just the one.

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like there's a question in there .. somewhere .. I just can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: how do you expect to handle `"Then he said, \"there's a quote in here too\""`

Comment: It looks like he's trying to grab values out of an SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match( '/"([^"]*)"/' , $string, $matches )  
# $matches is an array with the results
# ignore $matches[0]
# $matches[1] will contain the first string inside double-quotes
# $matches[2] will contain the second string inside double-quotes (if any)
```

more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Damn close thanks, unfortunately it spits out:

"example1"example1

Comment: Oops, I just corrected the answer. Please see the updated answer above. Basically, you just need to ignore the first element of the `$matches` array. The results you need are in the 2nd and 3rd elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to replace text, following a certain regex would help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

OR, if you're not wanting to replace text, you can match it using:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I managed it in a slightly backwards way, using the basis of bowsersenior's answer and some simple counting!

```
    //Find amount of Speech marks
$stringCount = substr_count($newstring, '"'); 


if ($stringCount == 2){

    preg_match( '/".*?"/' , $newstring, $matches);

    foreach ($matches as $data) 
    {
    print_r($data);
    }


}else{

    //Get first speech marks

    preg_match( '/".*?"/' , $newstring, $matches);

    foreach ($matches as $data) 
    {
    print_r($data);
    }


    //Get second speech marks

     $endString =  substr($newstring,-4);

    echo $endString;


}
```

Comment: (The data in the last speech marks is always 2 characters long btw - that's what makes this work!)